# Interpret Tcl commands in different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcl

In my project I have a main `Tcl_Interp` object with a lot of different custom commands and I want to call `Tcl_Eval` to interpret commands in multiple C++ threads. Since each `Tcl_Interp` is attached to its thread it's not possible use the main interpreter from another threads and interpreters I create with `Tcl_CreateInterp` could execute only default Tcl commands, but not my custom commands.

So is there a way to create a copy of main interpreter for each thread?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. It is generally advised to post code that illustrates how you have attempted to solve this problem already, rather than ask for someone to come up with example code for you.

Comment: Your attempt gives potential answerers a baseline from which they can compose answers as well as providing a hook future askers struggling with a similar problem can use to better understand the answers. Plus do not underestimate the social importance of showing your work.

Comment: Just add your custom commands to each thread's tcl interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

> So is there a way to create a copy of main interpreter for each
>   thread?

The script-level way is to provide for a [serializer](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.4004&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Using Tcl's excellent introspection (`info commands` etc.) to turn the current's interp state into a canonical script which is then sourced in another interp created using `Tcl_CreateInterp`.

[NaviServer](https://naviserver.sourceforge.io/n/manual/files/tcl-overview.html#section5) calls this blueprinting and provides a [scripted serializer](https://bitbucket.org/naviserver/naviserver/src/master/tcl/nstrace.tcl) as a starting point. Watch out for `nstrace::statescript`.

Comment: It would be a very nice addition to Tcl's batteries to have a serializer on board. NaviServer's one is only a starting point, as it does not support certain Tcl features (TclOO) etc.

Comment: See also the [Tclers' Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Dumping+interpreter+state).

Comment: If I want to replicate features in many interpreters, I put the code to create them in a file and then just `source` it where needed. Or I make a package.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Agreed, but creating a copy of one interpreter's state means to copy also the runtime state (e.g., global vars, dynamically added commands) which is sth. different than initialising an array of interps to the same vanilla state.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `Tcl_AppInitProc` to create your custom commands, that *only* runs in the main thread. Other threads default to being vanilla. The way to fix this is to register a *static package* during the running of the `Tcl_AppInitProc` that you can then `load` specially in each thread (when you create it) to gain your custom commands. (You'd better write your commands to be thread-safe or interpreter-bound/thread-agnostic, but that's your problem.)

Specifically:

```
int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    // Name is arbitrary, but needs to match [load] call in Tcl
    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "myCustom", MyCustomPerThreadInit, NULL);
    // Other main thread initialisation here
    return TCL_OK;
}
int MyCustomPerThreadInit(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    // Register your worker thread commands here
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

And then in each thread, you do this first:

```
load {} myCustom
```

You'll need to remember to do that in your main thread too if you want those commands there. Or you might split your commands into those for the main thread and those for the workers. Your choice.